# Convert octal number to string value by using sqlite statements in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to insert a special character values into my sqlite table. For that i have used following query, that contains octal values.

```
 "INSERT INTO \"manufacturers\" VALUES(NULL,NULL,NULL,'1970-01-01 00:00:00','1970-01-01 00:00:00','35','A Priorite\\047');"
```

when i displaying the names it doesn't converted to corresponding string value, it displays the same octal value inserted as (A Priorite\047);

Now i need an suggestion to convert the octal value to string or char by using sqlite statements.

I know we can easily obtain it by using java code but my requirement is to do it by use of  sqlite statements. Here the last value is the name field which is contains the octal value of \047(as string ').

I've also tried to convert the decimal value to char, it works fine. In my case, if i convert the octal value  to decimal value then i can easily convert to char. but i can't convert octal to decimal.

Note: I'm having thousands of record, so can't manually insert the special characters into each row of table. And I'm not supposed to insert the values manually.

Thanks in Advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you escaping slash? `'A Priorite\047'` should work.

Comment: No it doesn't work for me. I'm getting  error like this >>>android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "'A Priorite'');" (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO "manufacturers" VALUES(NULL,NULL,NULL,'1970-01-01 00:00:00','1970-01-01 00:00:00','35','A Priorite'');>>>

Comment: I agree with @CL, use parameters. Correct escaping in Java/C is using `\0###`, where ### are octal digits.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Could you please brief about your previous one? it takes next three digits after the backward slash. Now the problem is in placing the correct backward slash in my code. i'm using java program.

Comment: ### from `1` to `377`. But SQLite is complaining about statement, you MUST use parameters as @CL answer.

Comment: Now it works @LS_dev. I've posted my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not have octal escapes.

In Android, you should just use parameters to insert strings:

```java
String sillyDate = "1970-01-01 00:00:00";
String someNumberAsString = "35";
String name = "A Priorite\047";
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO \"manufacturers\" VALUES(NULL,NULL,NULL,?,?,?,?)",
           new Object[] { sillyDate, sillyDate, someNumberAsString, name });
```

If you really want to do this in SQL, you have to use a hexadecimal [blob literal](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue) and convert that to text:

```java
"INSERT INTO \"manufacturers\" VALUES(NULL,NULL,NULL,'1970-01-01 00:00:00',"+
"'1970-01-01 00:00:00','35','A Priorite' || x'27');"
```

Please note that in SQL, quotes inside strings can be escaped by doubling them:

```java
"INSERT INTO \"manufacturers\" VALUES(NULL,NULL,NULL,'1970-01-01 00:00:00',"+
"'1970-01-01 00:00:00','35','A Priorite''');"
```

Comment: I resolved my problem. Now it's working cool. I just changed my insert query to below one.

     "INSERT INTO \"manufacturers\" VALUES(NULL,NULL,NULL,'1970-01-01 00:00:00','1970-01-01 00:00:00','35','A Priorite\047'');"

Thanks for LS_dev. I accept @CL's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. Now it's working cool. I just changed my insert query to below one.

```
 "INSERT INTO \"manufacturers\" VALUES(NULL,NULL,NULL,'1970-01-01 00:00:00','1970-01-01 00:00:00','35','A Priorite\047'');"
```

Thanks to @LS_dev and @CL. I accept @CL's answer.