# reading octal from sqlite - ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm tring to Insert special characters into Sqlite and then trynig to  read data from sqlite,
but im facing some issue, 
i using follwing query to insert value to sqlite

INSERT INTO manufacturers VALUES(35,NULL,NULL,'KARTHICK\047');  in this query   KARTHICK\047 has octal value,  so when i try to read and displays the KARTHICK into my tableview, im getting (KARTHICK\047) instead of (KARTHICK'),

octal value \047 is special character of ' (')

My Insert code is following:

```
 id<PLPreparedStatement> stmt = [db prepareStatement:[NSString stringWithCString:kInsertManufacturer
                                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[stmt bindParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      ( manufacturerID == nil ) ? [NSNull null] : manufacturerID,
                      ( manufacturerName == nil ) ? [NSNull null] : manufacturerName,
                      ( manufacturerAlias == nil ) ? [NSNull null] : manufacturerAlias,
                      ( theDateCreated == nil ) ? [NSNull null] : theDateCreated,
                      ( theDateModified == nil ) ? [NSNull null] : theDateModified,
                      ( theDateDeleted == nil ) ? [NSNull null] : theDateDeleted, nil]];

if( [stmt executeUpdate] == NO ) {
    NSLog(@"kInsertManufacturer failed");
    [stmt close];
    return NO;
}
```

INSERT QUERY IS:  const char * kInsertManufacturer = "INSERT INTO manufacturers (manufacturer_id, name, alias, date_created, date_modified, date_deleted) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

INSERT INTO manufacturers VALUES(35,NULL,NULL,'1970-01-01 00:00:00','1970-01-01 00:00:00',35,'KARTHICK\047');

One of my fried fixed this issue in Android, but i couldn't able to fix in IOS,
Andoid:
[Convert octal number to string value by using sqlite statements in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210430/convert-octal-number-to-string-value-by-using-sqlite-statements-in-android)

please help me to sort out this issue

Comment: Show the actual code for creating your insert statement.

Comment: I doubt that SQLite recognizes C escape sequences (why would it?). Create a string that contains the actual character and insert **that** into the database.

Comment: You have shown three different INSERT statements. Which one are you actually using?

Comment: im using this :  INSERT INTO manufacturers VALUES(35,NULL,NULL,'1970-01-01 00:00:00','1970-01-01 00:00:00',35,'KARTHICK\047');

Answer (score 0):

You can escape your quotes by doubling them.

```sql
sqlite> CREATE TABLE names (name string);
sqlite> INSERT INTO names VALUES ("'""");
sqlite> SELECT * FROM names WHERE name == "'""";
'"
sqlite>
```

or

```sql
sqlite> CREATE TABLE names (name string);
sqlite> INSERT INTO names VALUES ('''');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM names WHERE name == "'";
'
sqlite>
```